# Set all xml nodes as CDATA

Tags: c#, xml, cdata

I have an xml with the following structure:

```
<rootNode>
<category name="test1">
    <string name="n1">n1</string>
    <string name="n2"><![CDATA[n2]]></string>
    <string name="n3">&lt;&lt;n3</string>
</category>
<category name="test2">
    <string name="n111">n111</string>
    <string name="n2"><![CDATA[&lt;&lt;n2]]></string>
    <string name="n3 &amp;">
        <![CDATA[n3
        multiline]]>
    </string>
</category>
```

`rootNode` has multiple `category` nodes, with multiple "string" nodes. Need to make all nodes `CDATA`. All my attempts failed, especially because of the nodes from "test2" (change node.InnerText, parse text with string.Replace etc.)

expected result:

```
<rootNode>
<category name="test1">
    <string name="n1"><![CDATA[n1]]></string>
    <string name="n2"><![CDATA[n2]]></string>
    <string name="n3"><![CDATA[<<n3]]></string>
</category>
<category name="test2">
    <string name="n111"><![CDATA[n111]]></string>
    <string name="n2"><![CDATA[&lt;&lt;n2]]></string>
    <string name="n3 &amp;">
        <![CDATA[n3
        multiline]]>
    </string>
</category>
```

Comment: And what have you tried? What parser are you using?

Comment: when trying to change InnerText, i used XmlDocument (the problem was that the output xml had <string name="n1">&lt;![CDATA[n1]]&gt;</string>). Also tried System.IO.File.ReadAllText + String.Replace (the problem was with multiline cdata, "&lt;" within existing cdata that needs to remain the same, "&amp;" within attribute name that needs to remain the same)

Comment: Please edit your question if you have more information. Include the code you have used so far.

Comment: After more digging, I solved it by clearing InnerText and adding a new CData section. Replying bellow with the answer. Thanks anyways, gunr2171!

Comment: Good examples of why you shouldn;t try and do arbitrary search replace on XML without being careful about the XML spec and contents.

Comment: Also not that when reading the XML, they will normally return a `<![CDATA[...]]>` identically to correctly encoded text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml");
var elements = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/rootNode/category/string");
foreach (XmlNode element in elements)
{
    //check if content of <string> is not CData section
    if(!(element.FirstChild is XmlCDataSection))
    {
        XmlCDataSection cdata = doc.CreateCDataSection(element.InnerText);
        //replace inner text with CData section
        element.ReplaceChild(cdata, element.FirstChild);
    }
}

doc.Save("path_to_xml_file.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void AddCData(string path) {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in root.SelectNodes("/rootNode/category/string")) {
            AddCData(childNode);
        }
        doc.Save(path + "_output.xml");
    }

    private void AddCData(XmlNode node) {
        string innerText = node.InnerText;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerText)) {
            if (!innerText.StartsWith("<![CDATA[")) {
                var newCDATA = node.OwnerDocument.CreateCDataSection(innerText);
                node.InnerText = "";
                node.AppendChild(newCDATA);
            }
        }
    }
```